# Why are these changes not committed to the database?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has two related fields. This snippet tries to set the value of one based on the value of the other field.

```
DataTable DT1 = new DataTable();
DT1 = countryDetailTableAdapter1.GetDataByNullYearMonth();
foreach (DataRow row in DT1.Rows)
{
    try
    { 
        DateTime YM1 = (DateTime)row["YearMonth"];
        String S = GetYearMonthFrm(YM1);
        row["MyYearMonth"] = S;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}

countryDetailTableAdapter1.Update(rEATCountryDetail.CountryDetail);
```

The method `GetYearMonthFrm()` returns a string based on the `DateTime` input. It's already being tested and used before.

The query `GetDataByNullYearMonth();` is returning the right results.

The assignment statement `row["MyYearMonth"] = S` is assigning the right value.

However the assignation does not commit to the database and after execution the values of `MyYearMonth` field is still `NULL`. Which are my mistakes?

Comment: Well, what is `rEATCountryDetail.CountryDetail` and how does it relate to the data you edited? What happens if you use `countryDetailTableAdapter1.Update(DT1);` ?

Comment: And why don't you just do an update query?

Comment: Not related but there isn't really much point to wrapping an exception and showing a message box, is there?  I thought that was the default WinForms behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try them both.

Comment: Thanks @TonyHopkinson, I followed your suggestion and it worked great.